# iphone app unable to access server - previously working

Tags: iphone

I've run into a funny problem. Our app, which was working prior to Saturday, can't connect to the server to get the necessary data. The server is fine, everything is up and running and I have rebooted it. The Support Tech has said the same. So it points to either the code having something that didn't change, or the ip/database info changed and the code is using the old info; as far as I know, we've changed nothing. Will I have to check the code?(I didn't write it, someone was hired to do it) or is there something else that could be causing the problem?

The error message:
"The app is currently unable to connect to the server. Please try again."

It's a very unspecific error message so I'm assuming the developers of the app put that specific message in themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the app on an iPhone you may be able to diagnose (but not necessarily fix) this without getting into the code. [Download Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp) and use [this tutorial](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html) to setup the iPhone so you can watch the network traffic. This will allow you to see exactly what requests the app is making to the server and you may be able to figure out the problem. Either your request isn't making it to the server or the server is returning an error message. Either way Fiddler should be able to give you that answer.

**EDIT:**

[HTTP Scoop](http://tuffcode.com/) is a pretty easy to use client for the Mac that does what Fiddler does for PC. You can use it for free for 2 weeks so that should be enough to help you out.

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) would also work. I know you can get a free trial for that as well.

Comment: Is there something similar for Mac?

Comment: Updated my answer with links to Mac programs.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at Paros proxy. It's an open source Java HTTP proxy which runs on the mac. I use it all the time for debugging server requests: http://www.parosproxy.org/